# How do i call a sub using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, html

I want to run a vb function using ajax.
This is the function that runs the ajax query.

```
 function runajax() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '*.aspx/prueba',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                await: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loading').show();
                },
                error: function (message) {
                    alert("ERROR")
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loading').hide(); alert("COMPLETE");
                }
            });
            return false;
       }
```

on the function inside the *.aspx.vb i have this:

```
<WebMethod()>
  Public Function prueba() as string
  Dim hola as string = "hola"
Label2.Text = "IT WORKS"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me,Page.GetType(),"pop","openModal();",true
  Return hola
End Function
```

what i want to do is to show a loading div while the function is working, then the function calls a modal.

Comment: Why not just do the `openModal()` in the `ajax Complete or Success`???

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: create a loading div, like a spinner or whatever and make it as display:none, on function start of runajax make the div css to display:block, and on success make display to none and in error case too

Comment: @epascarello it never runs the function in the aspx.vb

Comment: @RyanWilson cause i need to show a loading div while runing the sub. at the end of the sub it shows a modal depends on the results the sub will give.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS that already works, what i need its to run the sub or function i'm calling :/ it seems like it never runs the sub/function